# How to make responsive typography on Underscores (wordpress)?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive, typography

Trying to figure out how to use underscores. Before, to make typography responsive font for different screens, I would usually write different media queries as follows:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    html{
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
      etc..
}

   @media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
        html{
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 0.5rem;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 1.3rem;
        }
          etc..
    }
```

Using underscores, how do I change the parent font-size so the child elements can have an `rem` size?

I tried adding the font-size as it seems to be the parent element (?)

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Typography
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
body,
button,
input,
select,
optgroup,
textarea {
    color: #404040;
    font-family: Merriweather, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color:red;


}
```

What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. If you use `rem`s the only thing you need to control all your fonts depending on the viewport is to change the font size of the root element lets say `html`:

```
html {
    font-size: 12px;
}

p {
   font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.footer {
   font-size: .9rem;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { 
   /* now the basis for all the font sizes set in
   rems is 10px. For example, font-size for p is 10*1.1 = 11px. 
   Previously it was 1.1*12 = 13.2px. */
   html {
       font-size: 10px;
   }
}
```

Also you could use so called [fluid typography](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/) and combine it with the previous approach to get responsiveness (fonts will scale upon each resize attempt, not only after passing certain limits):

```
html {
  font-size: calc(14px + (26 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
}
```

It scales font size for `html` in 14px - 26px range depending on the viewport sizes 300px - 1600px.

**PS**. besides, here

```
font-size:20px;
font-size: 1rem;
```

you first set 20px and then rewrite it with 1rem, so it didn't have any effect. You may want to remove `font-size: 1rem;`. It will set font size equal to 20px for parent element (body), but also it will do so for other elements given there (inputs, buttons etc.) Approach involving `html` element is a common one and it is cleaner.

Comment: I was confused because in underscores for wordpress, they have  a commented typography section and it doesn't have html class defined

Comment: html isn't a class. It is just a html element like many others. All the css properties can be overwritten. You can remove, edit them or add new ones to get what you want. All the browsers have predefined styles and the default font-size is 16px. That is the base for rems if you don't change it.